# pandas variable value in html body

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I am trying to use a variable value in email html body inside python def but I get this error

`TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11989') dtype('<U11989') dtype('<U11989')`

I have tried these steps

```
    1) query_fo_count = "select count(*) from fo"
    2) fo_count = pd.read_sql(query_fo_count, conn)
    3) <lable>data record count:""" +fo_count+ """</label>
```

I am using `fo_count` to extract the value in the body but I do get this error when I execute

`TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11989') dtype('<U11989') dtype('<U11989')`

code:

```
    query_fo_count = "select count(*) from fo"
    fo_count = pd.read_sql(query_fo_count, conn)
    mail.HTMLBody = """<html>...
    <lable>data record count:""" +fo_count+ """</label>...</html>
```

I want the value to be printed. I have the value in fo_count=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
mail.HTMLBody = """<html>...
<lable>data record count:""" +str(fo_count.values[0])+ """</label>...</html>
```